# Ajax call only fires first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have an ajax call set to delete a record from a table (made by django-tables2).  Every row has a delete button with a class of `delete_relationship_button` and an id of the pk of the relationship record.  The ajax call works perfectly... once.  Subsequent calls do nothing--the network tab and console both show no results.  I see others have had this problem, but the solutions all involve using `.live` which is deprecated.

Any ideas?  Would also love an explanation or a point in the direction of why this is happening.

```
$('.delete_relationship_button').on('click', function(){
    relationship_pk = this.id;
    console.log(relationship_pk);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/app/relate/delete/',
        data: {'relationship_pk':relationship_pk},
        success: function(data){
            $('#relationship_tables').html(data);
        }
    })
})


def delete_relationship(request):
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        relationship_pk = request.POST.get('relationship_pk')
        relationship = ItemRelationship.objects.get(pk=relationship_pk)
        source = relationship.source
        relationship.delete()
    except:
        pass
    db_table, component_table = get_relationships(source)
    return render(request, 'who/subtemplates/relationships.html', 
        {'db_table': db_table, 'component_table': component_table,})
```

Comment: Just try `$(document).on('click', '.delete_relationship_button', function(){`

Comment: Brilliant!  Want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's best to delegate the event to a static parent of `.delete_relationship_button` instead of `document` for better performance. Attaching the click event to `document` would cause it to be processed every time anywhere the page is clicked. Processed means it checks to see whether `.delete_relationship_button` was the actual element clicked, before executing the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  have to use [delegation using `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically loaded content.

So, change

```
$('.delete_relationship_button').on('click', function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_relationship_button', function(){
```